# Escrevendo código em PHP sem caracteres especiais

Tags: php

Existe uma maneira de imprimir caracteres especiais no PHP usando apenas o código com caracteres ascii?

Por exemplo, em javascript, podemos usar \u00e1 no meio do texto.
Em Java, podemos usar \u2202 por exemplo.

E no PHP? Como posso usá-lo?

Eu não quero incluir caracteres especiais no meu código.

Comment: Você quer saber como imprimir carateres unicode numa string php ?

Comment: Além da resposta do Guilherme, você pode usar chr( ) para representarqualquer byte (ou sequência deles, concatenando) fazendo a combinaçao que desejar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Novidades no PHP7:

- [Sintaxe de escape de códigos Unicode](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax)

Existe suporte para sintaxe de escape de códigos Unicode, por exemplo:

```
<?php
echo "\u{00e1}\n";
echo "\u{2202}\n";
echo "\u{aa}\n";
echo "\u{0000aa}\n"; //o mesmo que o anterior mas com zeros a esquerda
echo "\u{9999}\n";
```

Será imprimido como:

```
á
∂
ª
ª
香
```

Exemplo no ideone: https://ideone.com/2Tcsed

> Nota 1: o `\n` é somente para quebra de linha é só pra separar os `echo`s, no HTML use `<br>`
>
> Nota 2: Somente aspas-duplas suportam isto, aspas simples assim `echo '\u{aa}';` não irá funcionar

---

### Sintaxe de escape no PHP5

No PHP antes do 7 (ou seja o 5) existia (e ainda existe) esta sintaxe:

```
\x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}
```

Que usa a notação hexadecimal e se limita a 1 ou 2 dígitos após o `\x` e assim como o unicode (`\u{[0-9A-Fa-f]+}`) também deve ser usado nas notações de aspas duplas.

Então para escrever um caractere unicode será necessário usar duas ou mais vezes o `\x` (já que caracteres unicodes são formados assim), por exemplo `\xc3\xa1` equivaleria ao `\u{00e1}`, exemplo ambos imprimem `á`:

```
<?php
echo "\xc3\xa1\n";
echo "\u{00e1}\n";
```

Comparando ambos:

```
if ("\xc3\xa1" === "\u{00e1}") {
    echo 'São iguais';
} else {
    echo 'São diferentes';
}
```

Vai exibir `São iguais`

- Link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

---

### Alternativa

Existe também a função [**`chr(...)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) ou até mesmo [**`sprintf(...)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) (ou até mesmo com `printf(...)`), por exemplo:

```
<?php

$caracterChr = chr(27);

$caracterPrintf = sprintf('%c', 27);

var_dump($caracterChr, $caracterPrintf);
```

Comparando ambos:

```
if ($caracterChr === $caracterPrintf) {
    echo 'São iguais';
} else {
    echo 'São diferentes';
}
```

Veja o exemplo no ideone: https://ideone.com/FJnGJp

Comment: Muito bom!! Não sabia! =)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho aproveitei e coloquei a sintaxe suportada no PHP5 ;)

Comment: Ficou completa a resposta!

Comment: Só faltou o `chr( )`, que serve pra representar qualquer coisa (inclusive UTF). cc @AndreiCoelho

Comment: @Bacco eu pensei em falar disto, mas 2 situações, 1. a resposta do Andrei já falava e até então ele não havia deletado, 2. a pergunta é escrever tal como é no Java e JavaScript, por isto achei que chr seria algo "burocrático", mas vou pensar em algo para citar ou escrever.

Comment: sim.. eu até pensei em restaurar a resposta depois do comentário do @Bacco . Mas achei que vc mesmo poderia coloca-la se achasse que fosse necessário. Mas, como vc mesmo disse, seria mais uma citaçao. Um complemento.

Comment: Eu gosto da idéia de restaurar, pq ai da pra trabalhar separado cada coisa (mas tem que dar uns "tapas" na restaurada, talvez com um exemplo em UTF-8) - Eu só não postei uma justamente pq vi a do Andrei

Comment: @Bacco adicionado uma breve explicação sobre chr e sprintf.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, muito obrigado, resposta completa e muito bem explicada, fantástico.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, só faltou um detalhe, chr e sprintf usando %c utilizam decimal para representar o binário, então tem que usar uma cadeia, para representar UTF-8 por exemplo: printf('%c%c', 0xC3, 0xA1);
echo chr(0xC3) . chr(0xA1);

Comment: @danilo sim é isso mesmo, é como com o `\x27`, também é em cadeia :[ ... somente o `\u` tem suporte pra unicode de fato. Por isso nem citei o chr antes, pois sabia que não era o que você desejava, adicionei na resposta a pedidos dos demais usuários

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, obrigado, sim o que eu procurava era para unicode.