# Requisição ajax com retorno inesperado

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, null

Tenho um código ajax que faz uma requisição em um arquivo php, e neste arquivo php tem somente um

> echo json_encode('teste')

No retorno vem a string `"teste"NULL`, sempre com este NULL iserido, após qualquer retorno.

```
$.ajax({
        url: BASE_URL+'produto/only_df',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
           alert(data);
        }
      });
```

Comment: é porque o `json_encode` faz a codificação de arrays, ele esta identificando "teste" como chave e sem valor, ou seja, valor NULL

Comment: Então... Tinha feito testes com um simples 'echo "teste"' também, mas o resultado é o mesmo. Tive a ideia de mudar o dataType para "html" e retornar somente uma string do php, mas a palavra NULL continua aparecendo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A funcão `json_encode` converte objetos e arrays em uma string JSON, mas não tem sentido converter uma string normal em JSON, ou seja, isso:

```
$foo = array(
     'bar' => 'Olá',
     'baz' => 'Mundo!'
);

echo json_encode($foo);
```

Vai virar isto (que é um json valido):

> ```
> {"bar":"Ol\u00e1","baz":"Mundo!"}
> ```

E isto:

```
$foo = array( 'Olá', 'Mundo!' );

echo json_encode($foo);
```

Vai virar isto (que é um json do tipo indexado/iteravel valido):

> ```
> ["Ol\u00e1","Mundo!"]
> ```

Agora isto:

```
echo json_encode('Olá mundo!');
```

Ou isto:

```
echo json_encode("Olá mundo!");
```

Irá apenas escapar a string aonde tiver acentos e aplicar as aspas:

```
"Ol\u00e1 mundo!"
```

Ou seja isto não é um JSON, é apenas uma string que pode ser usada com JSON, ou outras funções para JavaScript

> Leia sobre o escape unicode em: [Escrevendo código em PHP sem caracteres especiais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/293517/3635)
>
> ---
>
> **Nota:** se o documento não estiver salvo em um formato unicode, como utf8, `json_encode` não irá funcionar, irá retornar o valor `NULL`
>
> leia mais sobre como usar utf-8 em suas páginas PHP: [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635)

O uso de `json_encode` com strings é permitido pois o mesmo escape que é usado para JSON é usado para JavaScript, já que JSON é um formato aceito e muito usado com JS. Até mesmo o uso de atributos HTML chamado `data-*` podem fazer o uso deste escape.

Um exemplo de uso do `json_encode` com strings seria criar uma função gerada via PHP que será executada no JS, por exemplo se criasse um arquivo assim:

**foo.php**

```
<?php

echo 'foo(' . json_encode('teste') . ')';
```

E chamasse ele assim em uma outra página HTML:

```
<script src="foo.php"></script>
```

O script (e função) seria processada e baixada assim no navegador:

```
foo("teste");
```

Claro que você poderia fazer isso diretamente/manualmente, sem precisar de `json_encode`, mas imagine que a string tem quebra de linhas ou aspas, se fizer isto:

```
$arg = '
  olá mundo

  "isso é um teste"
';

echo 'foo("' . $arg . '")';
```

Vai gerar isto:

```
foo("
  olá mundo

  "isso é um teste"
");
```

O que vai dar erro de sintaxe ao ser executado no JavaScript, devido as quebras de linha e as "aspas" "dentro de aspas", mas se usar `json_encode`

```
$arg = '
  olá mundo

  "isso é um teste"
';

echo 'foo(' . json_encode($arg) . ')';
```

Ele vai escapar os acentos, quebras de linhas e aspas, ficando assim:

```
foo("\n      ol\u00e1 mundo\n\n      \"isso \u00e9 um teste\"\n    ")
```

O que vai rodar corretamente no JavaScript.

Comment: Muito obrigado, amigo, deu certo aqui. Vlw.